# Launching Android app from a link, and navigating to a particular URL?

Tags: java, android, webview

I have a webveiw within an Android app.  Is it possible to launch my app when the user clicks/touches on a URL (say in their Email app), and then navigate to a particular URL within the webview?  And if the app is not installed, just open the URL in Chrome?

So far I have tried this as suggested by @FD_:

```
    .
    .
    .
    </application>

    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
      <data android:host="mysite.com" android:scheme="http"></data>
    </intent-filter>

</manifest>
```

UPDATE:
I had the intent-filter in the wrong place within the manifest file.  It needs to be placed within the activity section.  It works now, however, it still does not take me to the actual URL. So if the url that is clicked on is mysite.com/page2, if you open the link using my app, it takes you to mysite.com, and not to mysite.com/page2.  Any idea how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is, using an Intent filter. I guess you want to receive only pages of a particular site. Add something like this to your activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
  <data android:host="www.stackoverflow.com" android:scheme="http"></data>
</intent-filter>
```

If the app is not installed, a webbrowser will also be able to open the site.

You can get the actual url using `getIntent().getData()`

Comment: Thanks.  I just tried this.  It's still opening up the link in Chrome. Is there anything I might be missing?

Comment: See my update.  It works not but still does not take me to the actual link.  It always goes to the root URL.